# Convert Stream<Stream<T>> to T[][] with Streams/Lambda's in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, java-8, java-stream

I am looking to see if there was a better way to solve my dilemma having to use these signatures (note:  the T[][] is required because of Spock testing and I am providing T[][] as a data provider)

My method signature is:

```
public <T> T[][] createArrays(Class<T> clazz, T...items)
```

I am using a static method which has the signature:

```
public static <T> Stream<Stream<T>> of(T...items)
```

and calculates all of the permutations of the passed array.

My solution, retyped by hand so forgive typos, is:

```
public static <T> T[][] createArrays(Class<T> clazz, T...items){
  Stream<Stream<T>> streams = EnumPerm.of(items);
  List<List<T>> lists = streams.map(s -> ).collect(toList()).collect(toList());
  T[][] outer = (T[][])(Array.newInstance(clazz,lists.size(),items.length);
  for(int x=0;x<lists.size();x++){
    List<T> innerList = lists.get(x);
    for(int y=0;y<items.length;y++){
      outer[x][y] = innerList.get(x);
    }      
  }

  return outer;
}
```

I attempted .map(s -> s.toArray(....)) but could not get T[] cast to work, the IntFunction generator to work, nor use the Array.newInstance to work.  I likely am missing something and would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Take care and thank you for your time in advance!!

Comment: If you are fine with unchecked casts, try `T[][] lists = (T[][])streams.map(x -> (T[])x.toArray()).toArray();`

Comment: Thanks for your response Sweeper, I did try that but I had an issue due to type erasure where the 'T' was not recognized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Array.newInstance` like this:

```
public static <T> T[][] createArrays(Class<T> clazz, T... items) {
    Stream<Stream<T>> streams = EnumPerm.of(items);
    return streams
        .map(s -> s.toArray(len -> (T[])Array.newInstance(clazz, len)))
        .toArray(len -> (T[][])Array.newInstance(items.getClass(), len));
}
```

without any intermediate `List`s.

There is a variant for creating arrays of the same type without unchecked casts, like this

```
public static <T> T[][] createArrays(Class<T> clazz, T... items) {
    Stream<Stream<T>> streams = EnumPerm.of(items);
    T[] template = Arrays.copyOf(items, 0);
    return streams
        .map(s -> s.toArray(len -> Arrays.copyOf(template, len)))
        .toArray(len -> (T[][])Array.newInstance(template.getClass(), len));
}
```

but since there is no existing array of type `T[][]`, we can’t avoid `Array.newInstance` for creating the outer array. But note that is doesn’t need the `clazz` parameter.

If you want to enforce the use of the specified `clazz` parameter for all arrays, you can use

```
public static <T> T[][] createArrays(Class<T> clazz, T... items) {
    Stream<Stream<T>> streams = EnumPerm.of(items);
    return streams
        .map(s -> s.toArray(len -> (T[])Array.newInstance(clazz, len)))
        .toArray(len -> (T[][])Array.newInstance(clazz, len, 0));
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm Holger, typing and all!  @Shadov, accepting this answer because doesn't throw exception.

Comment: I never thought to use the template like that, very nifty trick and one I am going to store away for future use!!! tyvm!!!